# Find string in file and copy until a specific character appears in Python

Tags: python, string, file

I have multiple .txt files with information in them that look like this after a conversion:

```
    >  **   ** **|** **     STYLE #        ** **|** **   DESCR  :  Potrero415;Tbl-
Rnd                 ** **\--------** **         ** **\--** **ZONE  1** **\--**
**           ** **\--** **ZONE  2** **\--** **      ** **\----** **      -T1-
-T2-  -T3-


                **
```

I want to grab everything from `DESCR:` until the next line where it starts `** **\--** ** ZONE 2 **`
so my string should look like this: `DESCR  :  Potrero415;Tbl-Rnd`

Note that in the file before this specific part there are multiple lines of text, and the word `DESCR` appears only where I want to copy from, no other appearances before.

I know that split could be used until the appearance of `** **\` 
All the files have the same format, just need to find from `DESCR:` to `** **`

I know I am risking to get downvotes on this post.
UPDATE:
I managed to find the appearances of the word using:

```
lines = test.readlines()
test.close()
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.find("DESCR") != -1:
        print("FOUND")
```

where `test` is the file that I have open

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Updated right now :)

Comment: "after a conversion", what kind of conversion?

Comment: From .htm to .txt using html2text

Comment: You mentioned that split could be used, why are you not using it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a regex.

`s` is the content of your file.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''    >  **   ** **|** **     STYLE #        ** **|** **   DESCR  :  Potrero415;Tbl-
... Rnd                 ** **\--------** **         ** **\--** **ZONE  1** **\--**
... **           ** **\--** **ZONE  2** **\--** **      ** **\----** **      -T1-
... -T2-  -T3-
... 
... 
...                 ** '''
>>> 
>>> re.search('(DESCR\s*:.*?)\s*\*\* \*\*', s, re.DOTALL).group(1)
'DESCR  :  Potrero415;Tbl-\nRnd'
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cPAxv2/1)

(Preceding the regex with (?s) has the same effect as supplying the `re.DOTALL` argument.)

Comment: Thank you! And have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions

```
import re

match = re.search('(?=DESCR).*?(?=\*\*)', your_txt)
print(match.group(0))
```

Would output:

> DESCR  :  Potrero415;Tbl-Rnd

[Regex Demo with your test string](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/1574)

Where:

```
Positive Lookahead (?=DESCR)
Assert that the Regex below matches
DESCR matches the characters DESCR literally (case sensitive)
.*? matches any character 
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
Positive Lookahead (?=\*\*)
Assert that the Regex below matches
\* matches the character * literally (case sensitive)
\* matches the character * literally (case sensitive)
Global pattern flags
s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
```

Comment: Very clear explanation, thank you for your time sir!